# Why my subnet mask is not matching with my IP address?

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I have a class 'B' IP address 172.16.XXX.XXX in my machine. My Subnet mask is 255.255.255.XXX. I am studying networking now. So until now I didn't care about masking about all. But from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference) I get that class 'B' should have 255.255.0.0 as subnet mask. So why my machine is an exception?

My OS is Windows-7.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing network masks and subnet masks. A traditional class B network has a network mask of 255.255.0.0. A subnet of that traditional class B network can have a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a class 'B' IP address 172.16.XXX.XXX in my machine
>
> But from Wikipedia I get that class 'B' should have 255.255.0.0 as subnet mask.

The "class B" IANA-reserved private network actually has subnet mask **255.240.0.0**, not 255.255.0.0.

Let me offer some clairity on how subnet masks work.

IP addresses enable:

- multiple systems on a network to talk to each other.
- AND it also provides the basis for computers on one network to talk to those on another network.

So we have two things to identify, the computer, and the network it is on.  Part of the IP address starting from the left (but not all of it) is used to identify the network, and the rest identifies the computer itself.

The subnet mask determines where we make this split.  IP addresses and subnet masks are written in decimal for human readability, but the computer processes them in binary.  Decimal to binary works like this, as an example:

```
    128 |  64 |  32 |  16 |   8 |   4 |   2 |   1 |
   -----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
      1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 | = 129 in decimal
```

So look again:

```
255.240.  0.  0 = 11111111 11110000 00000000 00000000
172. 16.  0.  1 = 10101100 00010000 00000000 00000001
```

Anything that is covered by a 1 on the subnet mask belongs to the network, the others are available to give to computers.  (Since all legal subnet masks contains a number of 1s in a row followed by the rest being 0, it's usual to now just refer to it with a single number that just stands for the number of 1's in the subnet mask.  The above would be expressed with a /12, i.e. 172.16.0.1/12 instead of 172.16.0.1/255.240.0.0)

---

With that background, you can understand how subnetting works.

So you are operating a home network and have decided to use 172.16.0.0/24 for all systems on there.  Typically you'll be putting that information into a DHCP server which will then be responsible for setting up most of the rest of your systems.  You could just tell the DHCP server to give out a range of addresses in 172.16.0.0/12, maybe 172.16.0.1 through 172.16.254.255 and leave the rest for servers or anything else.  The subnet mask on all these would be set to 255.240.0.0 or /12.  I could have up to 1,048,576 minus 2 computers on this (0 must remain reserved and the highest is always the broadcast address).

But what if you wanted to use a second network for something, maybe DMZ or just to keep a few machines isolated.  This is where subnetting comes into play.

```
255.240.  0.  0 = 11111111 11110000 00000000 00000000 (/12)
172. 16.  0.  1 = 10101100 00010000 00000000 00000001
```

I can reserve a few bits here for networks, and then have multiple networks under my control, but with the ability to have less hosts in them.

So, if I wanted, I can tell my DHCP server to handout subnet mask 255.255.0.0, and a range of IP addresses like 172.16.0.1 through 172.16.255.254.  This would be network 0.

```
255.255.  0.  0 = 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 (/16)
                               XXXX   
172. 16.  0.  1 = 10101100 00010000 00000000 00000001
```

The `XXXX` are bits I'm reserving to assign to networks, not computers.

I can then tell a second router if I'm so inclined to handle 172.17.0.1 through 172.17.255.254.  They would be isolated, and I'd need a separate router to connect computers on 172.16.0.0/16 (16 = 255.255.0.0) and 172.17.0.0/16.

(This doesn't take into account NAT and trying to get internet connectivity to these networks which complicates things.)

I hope you get the idea.  You wouldn't really do this too much in real life in a home environment, but definitely in a business environment.  I mention all this just to let you know that 255.255.0.0 will work for 172.16.XXX.XXX as well as 255.240.0.0, for the above reason.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed and descriptive answer. Still you didn't answer how could my machine have subnet mask like 255.255.255.192 and still works? I presume the answer will same as mkalkov's. Is it? If you want to add some details in your answer, you are very welcome.

Comment: You notice above how I didn't have to do anything special really to use a subnet mask 255.255.0.0 instead of 255.240.0.0?  Same principle with any subnet mask that has more 1's on the left.  255.255.255.192 is a /26 and since it's "more" than 255.255.0.0 (a /16) or your original value 255.240.0.0 (/12) it will work.  I tried to explain above why you'd use a "greater" subnet mask than what you were orginally given.

Answer (score 4):

Classful addressing has been obsolete for more than a decade. Nobody cares about default subnet masks any more. You only need to know it because for some reason exams keep asking about it. It's completely routine to divide a /16 in class B space into /24's.

Answer (score 4):

Classful routing has been superceeded by [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing). So, the split between network and host parts of an IPv4 address is dictated by a subnet mask, and it does not matter which class the address fell in before. Hence, your machine is no exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you had a class C address before and a /24 sub-net mask was assigned automatically.
And when u changed the IP to a Class B address, the sub-net mask that does not change by default, remained as 255.255.255.0

In windows machines, sub-net mask is not auto-assigned when IPs are changed/edited.

If you use a 172.16.x.y IP address and a 255.255.255.z mask, the Host range will depend on value 'z'.
[image: Check Range]

```
When z= 0; Range 172.16.x.1 - 172.16.x.254
     z= 126; Range 1 - 126
     .
     .
     .
     z=252; Range 172.16.x.1 - 172.16.x.2
```